# Detectar "evento de download"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou disponibilizando um link para download de arquivos XML:

```
<a href="http://exemplo.com/link" download="">
   Baixe o XML do pedido
</a>
```

Porém, por se tratar de um processamento um pouco lento, devido ao número de funções necessárias, gostaria de colocar um `loading` na página para que o usuário não tenha a sensação de que nada esta acontecendo. Pois ao clicar várias vezes, o download também é feito várias vezes...

Até onde sei, não existe um evento `downlaod`, mas eu preciso exatamente simular esse comportamento, para poder encerrar o `loading` no momento em que o download de fato for realizado.

O `loading` que me refiro seria simples, eu mesmo faço, a minha questão é realmente simular o evento.

Gostaria de fazer na solução mais simples possível, sem utilizar algum plugin.

Comment: Kenny, não entendi bem, se você está usando um link, é porque o arquivo já está pronto correto? A única demora é no download em si, dependendo do tamanho do arquivo e da banda do usuário. Onde existe o processamento lento que você mencionou?

Comment: Não, na vdd é justamente o contrário, o download é rápido pois o arquivo é pequeno, mas o link não é para o arquivo direto, e sim para um outro sistema em outro servidor, que consulta em um sqlserver para buscar o arquivo em um diretório de outro servidor e fazer a leitura...sei que é confuso, mas o que importa é que realmente é o processamento que demora um pouco...

Comment: Kenny - o onclick não te atende? Outra maneira seria exibir um modal ou uma `div` sobrepondo sua página com o aviso de que o download está iniciando e uma opção pra fechar. Esse tópico aqui também pode te ajudar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download

Comment: @leonardopessoa, disparar o evento é simples, o meu problema é realmente em finaliza-lo automaticamente, não tinha pensado nessa solução com modal ou algum outro alerta, porém se a princípio puder tratar automaticamente eu prefiro, mas vamos ver...

Comment: Particularmente, nunca vi nenhum site que tivesse essa funcionalidade de detectar o fim do download. Seria interessante ver funcionando.

Comment: Sim, poderia ser tanto quando acabar como quando iniciar...

Comment: Não acredito que exista um evento para downloads, porque o download essencialmente é outro request. Uma alternativa pode ser usar esse link para gerar o arquivo via ajax. Aí fica fácil usar o loading. Quando o arquivo estiver pronto você recebe a resposta do ajax com a URL final para download e remove o arquivo algum tempo depois, com uma rotina no servidor.

Comment: É @RicardoMoraleida, eu pensei que talvez houvesse alguma solução simples para fazer essa simulação, mas creio que terei que utilizar algo do tipo...

Comment: @KennyRafael acho que é mais simples do que procurar uma solução cross-browser pra uma questão assim. Não muda nada pro usuário, ele vai ser redirecionado pro download de qualquer forma, só deixa de ser um link direto.

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download Usando cookies e GET/POST Também existe um plugin para isso http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/ embora eu não seja muito fã de usar plugins para esse tipo de coisas